# How to implement asynchronous rest webservice client using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I want to invoke rest webservice call asynchronously using spring 3.1 rest template. Currently we are using Resttemplate.getForObject method to invoke the rest webservice. Now as per the requirement we have to invoke another webservice method concurrently along with existing one. We are invoking this method call from EJB 2.1 stateless session bean by instantiating the method class.

Sample code is as below:-

```
public class MyImplServerBean extends EJBObject{
   RestServiceImpl restImpl = new RestServiceImpl(); 
   ArrayList<User> userDetailsList = restImpl.getUserDetails(123);
}

public class RestServiceImpl {

   RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

   public ArrayList<User> getUserDetails(int userId){

   ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
   String url = "http://localhost:7001/myUserService/userId";
   User user = template.getForObject(url, User.class);
   userList.add(user);
   return userList;
}
```

We now need to make getUserDetails method call asynchronously. I got the idea using @Async annotation but not aware how to exactly implement.
Can you please help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) tutorial to accomplish a similar task. I did some modifications. Here is how to get it working.

1) Create a configuration class and make sure it is scanned by ApplicationContext. I use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer
{
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

2) Annotate your method with

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
```

Your method must either return void or Future.

3) Make sure the async method is public and called from another class. This way Spring "sees" the annotation when the method is invoked reflectively.